# OneDrive for Business API - Shared with Me

Tags: onedrive

I have successfully received a list of items using the OneDrive API, however the items that have been Shared with Me in OneDrive don't appear.

> "When a shared folder is added to OneDrive, the folder appears in the root..."
>
> "When enumerating a collection of items, shared folders appear as
> items with the remoteItem facet."

https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/working-with-links.htm

It would appear the items in OneDrive's Shared with Me section should be returned with the following method:

`GET /drive/root/children`

However they aren't.

Is there a separate endpoint for Shared items?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you referenced is specifically referring to mounting scenarios. Unfortunately there is not currently a way to enumerate items shared with you that are not mounted, but we're definitely aware of the need to have such a mechanism!